# How can I make an NSViewController topmost in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, nsviewcontroller

I would like to know if there is a way to make one of my NSViewControllers stay on top of the rest of them in Xcode or Swift 2. I am also working with OS X Cocoa. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more context for this question?  What is the situation.  And by NSViewController does that mean you are working with OS X?

Comment: You mean your window

Comment: Ok I updated my post. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have NSViewControllers in multiple windows, and it's one of the windows that you want to keep on top of the others. This is done by setting the `window.level`:

```
window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.FloatingWindowLevelKey))
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says, "Value of type 'NSView' has no member 'level'. You are exactly right in what you assumed about my question. You are right!

Comment: That's because you have a NSView, whereas you need a NSWindow. If your NSView is in a variable called `view`, then you can get to the window with `view.window`, so therefore you can set the level with `view.window.level = ...`.